# how to run a java program which was wrapped by python in redhat services

Tags: java, python, celery, redhat

I have a python program which is wrapper for Java program. This python program executes the Java program. When I run this python program it works normally but when I run this as a red hat services it skips the java program and just runs the python program. When it has to run the java program it just prints 0 in the terminal. is it because Redhat services wont start another pid in the daemon mode? Please help me

This is the Redhat service code which runs the  /www/StartValidator.sh

```
[Unit]
Description=Message Broker Service
[Service]
Type=Simple
User=mbobbili
ExecStart=/bin/bash /www/StartValidator.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not anything RedHat specific. This is a part of a regular systemd service file... Also, I see nothing Celery and Python specific here as your systemd service runs a BASH script...

If `/www/StartValidator.sh` runs the Celery worker by any chance, then I strongly suggest you read the [Daemonization](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) section in the Celery documentation.

Since it is not clear to me what you mean by "*wont start another pid in the daemon mode*", I am going to assume you experienced the "typical" problem - when you run Celery worker again (either manually, or via systemd service), if it points to the same PID file, and there is a live process with PID in the existing file, then it is going to refuse to run, because you already have Celery worker running. Simply stop the existing process, and then it will all work.

Comment: We have a python program which runs Java Program. We instantiate the python program using a celery worker if we get any message to the celery worker. If I run celery -A proj -l info then everything works fine. But If I run it as a service so that celery will always listens, it skips just Java part and completes the program. How do we solve this problem

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code of that Celery task.